# Contact form 7 input box not clickable

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have one site developed in wordpress and One of my contact form is not working while clicking on input box i am not able to enter any deatils in that can any body check and suggest me solution I have tried many related to CSS but none of them are working.

Link of form https://kulorgroup.com/contact-us/

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this "jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" jquery on your page not let you click text box, remove "jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" from your contact page and check

Comment: Thank you @Tausif, but i need this as it is being used in swiping images in gallery

Comment: so i said remove it from contact page only not to all page.

Comment: that query page only blocking you to type , i just removed it and your page worked fine

Comment: Thank you again Mr Tausif you are right how can i removed it from contact page as i have added it in footer

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any plugin or something which disabled the selection to the website content and even not allow me to right click, while i checked it with original theme it works fine.

Comment: Thank you @ravi i have added jquery code to disable right click you can use function f12 for inspection